# Zend adapter - The supplied or instantiated driver object does not implement

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using Zend framework 2.4.11 and I'm trying to use the Zend Adapter.

I tried with these two case and still not work. I got this error.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The supplied or instantiated driver object does not implement Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface in....

My setting

```
            'driver' => 'Pdo', 
            'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=myhost.com',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '...',
```

and

```
            'driver' => 'PDO_MYSQL',  (also tried this: Pdo_Mysql) 
            'hostname' => 'myhost.com',
            'database' => 'mydb',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '...',
```

Any idea why?

Comment: How do you instantiate DB adapter?

Comment: I put this line > use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter; and then > $db = new Adapter($db_config); which db_config is the above setting. You see anything wrong?

Comment: There is something wrong with your configuration. I tried the simplest possible config from https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#zend-db-adapter and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
set in your autoload/config/local/global.php
'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'adapters' => array(
            'default_db' => array(
                'driver'         => 'Pdo',
                'dsn'      => 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=yourhost',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
            ),
        ),
    ),

access It with :
getServiceManager()->get('db');
```